# How to make use of Angular cli and gulp together

Tags: javascript, angular, gulp, angular-cli

I am trying to put together Angular cli and gulp and i want to make use of the live reload feature of gulp so that if any one changes any files in the Angular system the files will be built Automatically in the dist from where it will be served by my node server.

**I just want ng build not the ng serve as i want to build the files automatically not reuse the live reload of cli**

I have tried a lot to google the same but i am not able to put together any `what have i done stuff`

```
gulp.task('default', ['sdk', 'server'], function() {
  gulp.watch(['./common/models/*.js'], ['server']);
  gulp.watch(['./client/**/*.js'], ['angular']); // i am thinking of lisiting here please help
});
```

Please note

I need to just update the dist files always with the latest changes i know this can be expensive but can this be done very fast as this is a part of a big picture where i serve from the node server

Answer (score 0):

angular cli comes with a watch flag for `ng build`

```
ng build --watch
```

or

```
ng build -w
```

This will rebuild `dist` directory whenever a file changes

Comment: how do we have a gulp task for the same so that then i can serves files using node

Comment: @INFOSYS do you need gulp? ng build will build to your dist directory which node could serve

Comment: yes actually there is something more to it using loopback sdk and then pushing model changes need gulp

Comment: @INFOSYS So you'll need something like `gulp.watch(['./src/app/**/*', './src/index.html'], ['angular'])` (watch any other files as needed). Then run the ng build command in a gulp task